# How can I access the PseudoInverse() and AsArray() functions of DenseMatrix in MathNET?

Tags: c#, methods, mathnet-numerics

I am looking through the documentation of `Matrix` in `MathNet`, and have tried initializing my matrix in different ways.

```
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;

Matrix<double> a = Matrix<double>.Build(3, 3, myDoubleArray);
DenseMatrix b = new DenseMatrix(3, 3, myDoubleArray);
DenseMatrix c = new DenseMatrix(3);
```

However, when I look at the member functions that are available to me, I am unable to see functions such as `AsArray()` or `PseudoInverse()` even though they appear in the documentation [here](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double/Matrix.htm).

Why is this the case?  Are these extension methods that I need to add another `using` statement for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the [source](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/v3.14.0-beta03/src/Numerics/LinearAlgebra/Double/Matrix.cs#L499). `AsArray` and `PseudoInverse` are only in version 3.14 (still in beta, though).

Comment: Ah thank you, didn't realize that.  I checked and am running v3.13.1.